# change service request ride when click button on android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a button to open google map with travel mode request ride when clicked using this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+ mLocation.latitude + ","+ mLocation.longitude +"&f=d&dirflg=x"));
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

the question is,
is it possible to change the service (ie 'go-jek') as default? and set default between car or motorcyle?